# HTTP communication on port 80

Tags: httpwebrequest, webserver, httpresponse, priority-queue, port80

I'd like to understand how web servers handle large number of simultaneous HTTP requests and responses. Please keep in mind I'm new to network programming.

Can the web server send multiple HTTP responses on port 80 at the same time? Or do the responses have to be "serialized"?

Does the web server receive requests in a serialized fashion? If so then inserting into a priority queue probably needs to be fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that most web servers will process incoming requests in parallel by handling each request on a separate thread/process (by pulling thread from a threadpool or creating a new one). Usually, there is a cap on the number of requests that can be processed simultaneously (such as the maximum number of threads in the threadpool). Going beyond that cap means pending requests will wait in queue until another request finishes. If the server needs to do some asynchronous processing of the request, it may return the thread to the threadpool until it is ready to finish the request (such as with IHttpAsyncHandler in ASP.NET).

The server doesn't actually send back requests on port 80. The client will have its own port for that particular connection.

Comment: Would epoll be the Linux equivalent of IHttpAsyncHandler in ASP.NET?

Comment: @MrMusic While I am not an expert on Linux networking, I believe epoll is more analogous to I/O completion ports in Windows. The web server, such as Apache or IIS, would use epoll or I/O completion ports to asynchronously read data from the network socket. Usually, there is an application model running within the web server (such as a PHP module in Apache or ASP.NET in IIS). Some of the application models allow you to "release" the thread back to the threadpool while processing the server request. Node.js is an example of a server that tries to do just about everything asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new as well but have a little understanding of network communications.

It doesn't respond to multiple requests at the same time, one at a time, just very, very fast when functioning properly.

When info is sent out over the network regardless of what port it is, it is sent out in a packet.
In that packet is the header which defines, in your case that your asking about, the port number that it is attempting to use and other needed info.
After the header is the data. Size of the data in the packet varies on setting, ie computer, router/switch, and whatever else is involved.
Then finally the footer, which contains directions as to whether it is the last packet coming for that particular reguest or if not, what to look for in the next packet.

Hoped that helped to answer your question and maybe give you a few more questions.

Comment: I like Caleb's answer. More towards the webserver function. Sorry if mine wasn't what you were looking for.